# Найти элемент на странице jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть элементы с pm и дальше цифры:

```html
<div class="" id="">
  <div class="mes " id="pm2509">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2511">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2513">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2515">
    text
  </div>
  <div id="new"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно с помощью jquery найти максимальный #pm, обязательно DOM. Спасибо.

Comment: что значит _обязательно DOM_?

Comment: Код появляется динамически...

Comment: и? если его нет - значит он и не найдется :)

Comment: прошу вас, не используйте id не по назначению - для хранения информации! добавьте аттрибут `data-id="2511"` и в нем храните эти айдишники. выборка (или фильтрация) в таком случае будут надежнее и прозрачнее.

Comment: потому что это идентификатор элемента, а не поле для хранения данных. для того, чтобы выполнить то, что вы хотите (да, это реально и легко) нужно взять значение аттрибута id, отрезать кусок и использовать оставшуюся цифру. Зачем, если можно сразу сохранить этот индекс в чистом виде в отдельном аттрибуте и не мешать его в какие-то "id..." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы предложил исправить код на подобный

```
<div class="" id="">
  <div class="mes " id="pm2509" data-id="2509">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2511" data-id="2511">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2513" data-id="2513">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm2515" data-id="2515">
    text
  </div>
  <div id="new"></div>
</div>
```

и потом в js

```
var $max = null;
$('.mes').each(function(){
    if(!$max || $max.data('id') < $(this).data('id')){
        $max = $(this);
    } 
});
//здесь в $max искомый элемент
```

ну или если вы не намерены менять html, то

```
var $max = null;
$('.mes').each(function(){
    $(this).data('id', $(this).attr('id').replace('pm',''));
    if(!$max || $max.data('id') < $(this).data('id')){
        $max = $(this);
    } 
});
//здесь в $max искомый элемент
```

Comment: данный код выдает все содержимое id="pm2515", нужно только узнать максимальный id ))

Comment: и нужно в jquery

Comment: @skillful куда выдает? какое содержимое? этот код никуда содержимое id не выдает. в комментарии написано же: в переменной $max будет находиться искомый элемент.

Comment: хорошо, искомый элемент, только он минимальный, а нужно максимальный

Comment: @skillful не понимаю вашей проблемы. вы просили элемент с максимальным значением после pm. после выполнения кода в $max ссылка именно на такой элемент. в чем у вас проблема? как вы проверяете работу?